# why does all the text get printed on the same line?

Tags: php, heredoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Have I misunderstood what heredoc should do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058600/have-i-misunderstood-what-heredoc-should-do)

I read that *Here document* preserves the line breaks
and other whitespace (including indentation) in the text. But when I run the following script,everything gets printed on the same line. Why is it so ?

```
<?php 
$str = <<<HDC
 This is a sample text
 Some more sample text
 Even more sample text
HDC;
echo $str;
```

Comment: its working. http://codepad.org/h2jSMZZY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output actually does contain the line breaks. However, HTML (by default) ignores line breaks.

If you want the HTML to render the line breaks, wrap it in a `pre`:

```
<pre>
<?php 
$str = <<<HDC
 This is a sample text
 Some more sample text
 Even more sample text
HDC;
echo $str;
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you cannot use `<pre>` because `<pre>` always prints in fixed width, manually insert the `<br>` tags.

Comment: _"Or if you cannot use because always prints in fixed width..."_ what does that mean ?

Comment: I think @saplingPro knows about the `<br>` tag. He's just trying to fully grok `heredoc`s. Am I right?